# Как получить доступ к свойству

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как сделать чтобы при выборе radiobutton (дневной) поменять свойства календаря `local:DatePickerCalendar.IsMonthYear="True"` на `"False"`

xaml code

```
<GroupBox Padding="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <Button Background="Lavender">Периодичность</Button>
    </GroupBox.Header>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton x:Name="radioButtonDaily"  Margin="3" Checked="radioButtonDaily_Checked">Дневной</RadioButton>
        <RadioButton x:Name="radioButtonMonthly" IsChecked="True" Margin="3">Месячный</RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>

<DatePicker x:Name="myDatePicker" 
    local:DatePickerCalendar.IsMonthYear="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"
    local:DatePickerDateFormat.DateFormat="MMM-yyyy"
    Text="MMM-yyyy" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
</DatePicker>
```

cs code

```
private void radioButtonDaily_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButtonDaily.IsChecked == true)
    {
        myDatePicker. //<- тут их не видно 
    }
}
```

Классы `DatePickerCalendar` и `DatePickerDateFormat` брал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39111804/3373603)

Comment: отредактируйте заголовок если что

Comment: почему не привязать в xaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <RadioButton x:Name="radioButtonDaily"  Margin="3" Checked="radioButtonDaily_Checked">Дневной</RadioButton>

 <DatePicker x:Name="myDatePicker" 
     local:DatePickerCalendar.IsMonthYear="{Binding ElementName=radioButtonDaily, Path=IsChecked}"         
     local:DatePickerDateFormat.DateFormat="MMM-yyyy"
     Text="MMM-yyyy"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, а с таким подходом можно поменять DatePickerDateFormat.DateFormat="MMM-yyyy" на "dd-MM-yyyy"?

Comment: @Ruslan_K, Да, через триггеры